# Find the total time a javascript function takes by using the call tree in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, timing

I'm currently using the AOP Library meldjs and I would like to record timing for the new advised functions. As one can notice, function validateRegistration is the first one to be called and the functions below it are the remaining functions called from it, function checkLengths has the same scenario and they are the only functions which are not advised by meldjs (because their full name is shown and the other advised functions have the word advised in their name).

To record the time that function checkLengths took to execute should I take note of the time near it which is 0 ms self time and 3.1 ms total time? Or should I add all of the timings of the functions which were called from it, i.e. for total time I add 3.1(for checkLengths), followed by 3.1, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 0.1 and 0.1.

[image: Function Timings]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've searched for any sort of clues so that I could confirm what I should do but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: The first column title is "self time" and it's the function's own code time, while the second column includes all other functions invoked by the measured one. Pretty self-explanatory, I think. See also [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/).

Comment: But since the functions below it were called from it, shouldn't their total time add up the its total time?

Comment: No, because each encompassing entry's total time already includes the nested entry's total time.